# Add a circular progress icon inside the chip view

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I want to add a circular progress icon like

[image]

Inside a chip view in android. Some thing like this as the end product

[image]

Excuse the background of the progress bar indicator. I am not able to find any thing regarding this. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to create custom cardview and wrap circular progresssbar in it, that way you can achieve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour by setting programmatically the **`ChipIcon`** using an **`androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.CircularProgressDrawable`** if you want to align the loading indicator in the left side of your Chip or you can use the **`CloseIcon`** if you want to align it on the right side of the Chip.

**Align CircularProgressDrawable on the left side of chip:**

1.In your chip xml layout define the chipIconSize and padding attributes based on your needs like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chip"
    app:chipIconSize="25dp"
    app:iconStartPadding="5dp"
    app:iconEndPadding="5dp"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
```

2.Create programmatically your CircularProgressDrawable like below:

```
CircularProgressDrawable cpDrawable = new CircularProgressDrawable(this);
cpDrawable.setStyle(CircularProgressDrawable.DEFAULT);
cpDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
cpDrawable.start();
```

3.And set the above CircularProgressDrawable to your ChipIcon like below:

```
chip = findViewById(R.id.chip);
chip.setChipIcon(cpDrawable);
chip.setChipIconVisible(true);
```

**Align CircularProgressDrawable on the right side of chip:**

1.In your chip xml layout define the closeIconSize and closeIcon paddings attributes based on your needs like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chip"
    app:closeIconSize="25dp"
    app:closeIconStartPadding="5dp"
    app:closeIconEndPadding="5dp"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
```

2.Create programmatically your CircularProgressDrawable like above and set it on Chip CloseIcon like below:

```
 chip = findViewById(R.id.chip);
 chip.setCloseIcon(cpDrawable);
 chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
```

**Results will be like below:**

[image: left_side_loading]
[image: right_side_loading]

Comment: I followed the same method and was able to achieve it. Was going to add the answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I created a layout using relative layout, you can check this i hope you get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dummy_bg"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Electronics"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progrressciruclar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvlabel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

also create this dummy_bg in your drawables folder and paste the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You are creating a card view with the progressbar. Is there any way to use the chipview and use the progress indicator inside the chipview. The implementation is with chipview and replacing it with a new card will be lot more complex.